# Finding System modifiable attributes for each object class in Microsoft Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, apacheds

We could see attributes which are part of `systemMayContain` attributes list are user modifiable. If we consider the `computer` object class. 
Below is the definition of  object class
`( 1.2.840.113556.1.3.30 NAME 'computer' SUP user STRUCTURAL MAY (cn $ networkAddress $ localPolicyFlags $ defaultLocalPolicyObject $ machineRole $ location $ netbootInitialization $ netbootGUID $ netbootMachineFilePath $ siteGUID $ operatingSystem $ operatingSystemVersion $ operatingSystemServicePack $ operatingSystemHotfix $ volumeCount $ physicalLocationObject $ dNSHostName $ policyReplicationFlags $ managedBy $ rIDSetReferences $ catalogs $ netbootSIFFile $ netbootMirrorDataFile $ msDS-AdditionalDnsHostName $ msDS-AdditionalSamAccountName $ msDS-ExecuteScriptPassword $ msDS-KrbTgtLink $ msDS-RevealedUsers $ msDS-NeverRevealGroup $ msDS-RevealOnDemandGroup $ msDS-RevealedList $ msDS-AuthenticatedAtDC $ msDS-isGC $ msDS-isRODC $ msDS-SiteName $ msDS-PromotionSettings $ msTPM-OwnerInformation $ msTSProperty01 $ msTSProperty02 $ msDS-IsUserCachableAtRodc $ msDS-HostServiceAccount $ msTSEndpointData $ msTSEndpointType $ msTSEndpointPlugin $ msTSPrimaryDesktopBL $ msTSSecondaryDesktopBL $ msTPM-TpmInformationForComputer $ msDS-GenerationId $ msImaging-ThumbprintHash $ msImaging-HashAlgorithm $ netbootDUID $ msSFU30Name $ msSFU30Aliases $ msSFU30NisDomain $ nisMapName ) )`

Below is the list `systemMayContain` attributes
`"systemMayContain":["msImaging-HashAlgorithm","msImaging-ThumbprintHash","msDS-GenerationId","msTPM-TpmInformationForComputer","msTSSecondaryDesktopBL","msTSPrimaryDesktopBL","msTSEndpointPlugin","msTSEndpointType","msTSEndpointData","msDS-HostServiceAccount","msDS-IsUserCachableAtRodc","msTSProperty02","msTSProperty01","msTPM-OwnerInformation","msDS-RevealOnDemandGroup","msDS-NeverRevealGroup","msDS-PromotionSettings","msDS-SiteName","msDS-isRODC","msDS-isGC","msDS-AuthenticatedAtDC","msDS-ExecuteScriptPassword","msDS-RevealedList","msDS-RevealedUsers","msDS-KrbTgtLink","volumeCount","siteGUID","rIDSetReferences","policyReplicationFlags","physicalLocationObject","operatingSystemVersion","operatingSystemServicePack","operatingSystemHotfix","operatingSystem","networkAddress","netbootSIFFile","netbootMirrorDataFile","netbootMachineFilePath","netbootInitialization","netbootDUID","netbootGUID","msDS-AdditionalSamAccountName","msDS-AdditionalDnsHostName","managedBy","machineRole","location","localPolicyFlags","dNSHostName","defaultLocalPolicyObject","cn","catalogs"]`

If we consider `msImaging-HashAlgorithm, msImaging-ThumbprintHash, msTPM-TpmInformationForComputer, msTSEndpointPlugin, msTSEndpointType, msTSEndpointData, msDS-HostServiceAccount, msTSProperty02, msTSProperty01, msTPM-OwnerInformation, msDS-RevealOnDemandGroup, msDS-NeverRevealGroup, msDS-PromotionSettings, msDS-AuthenticatedAtDC, msDS-RevealedUsers, msDS-KrbTgtLink, volumeCount, rIDSetReferences, policyReplicationFlags, physicalLocationObject, operatingSystemVersion, operatingSystemServicePack, operatingSystemHotfix, operatingSystem, networkAddress, managedBy, machineRole, location, localPolicyFlags, dNSHostName, defaultLocalPolicyObject, cn, catalogs` these fields are user modifiable and part of `systemMayContain` list.
When tried with setting value while creating `Computer` object it allows. Is there any way to know only system fields which does not allow user input? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is specific to Active Directory. MSDN has documentation for each schema attribute -- e.g. [CN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-canonicalname) -- which documents if the attribute is "system only" or not.

For an automated process, search at the base `cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=example,dc=com` with the filter `(&(ldapDisplayName=AttributeName))`and return the value of `systemOnly`. E.G. this shows that operatingSystemServicePack is user writable.

```
***Searching...
ldap_search_s(ld, "cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=example,dc=com", 2, "(&(ldapDisplayName=operatingSystemServicePack))", attrList,  0, &msg)
Getting 1 entries:
Dn: CN=Operating-System-Service-Pack,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
systemOnly: FALSE;
```

You can also list *all* of the system-only attributes by using the filter `(&(systemOnly=TRUE))` and returning `ldapDisplayName`

```
***Searching...
ldap_search_s(ld, "cn=schema,cn=configuration,dc=example,dc=com", 2, "(&(systemOnly=TRUE))", attrList,  0, &msg)
Getting 189 entries:
Dn: CN=OM-Object-Class,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: oMObjectClass; 

Dn: CN=Canonical-Name,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: canonicalName; 

Dn: CN=Managed-Objects,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: managedObjects; 

Dn: CN=MAPI-ID,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: mAPIID; 

Dn: CN=Mastered-By,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: masteredBy; 

Dn: CN=Top,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: top; 

Dn: CN=NTDS-DSA-RO,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: nTDSDSARO; 

Dn: CN=Application-Process,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,dc=example,dc=com
lDAPDisplayName: applicationProcess; 
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I could retrieve all the attributes from attribute schema and can check for system attributes. However, I can still see some conflict in metadata. If we consider the attribute [netbootSIFFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-netbootsiffile) and  [netbootMirrorDataFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-netbootmirrordatafile) as per `Attribute Schema` these are not `System Only` attributes but as per `Update Privilege` in the mentioned links `This value is set by the system` which is not correct.Is there any way to find this conflict.